# Is the following logic true?

Tags: logic

Is the following logic true?

$ (\forall x)(\forall y)[(p(x) \wedge S(x,y)) \rightarrow Q(y)] \wedge (\exists x)B(x) \wedge (\forall x)(B(x) \rightarrow p(x))\wedge (\forall x)(\exists y)S(x,y) \longrightarrow (\exists x) Q(x) $ $$ $$ I have tried in the way- 
 Let p(x) denote dog and Q(y) denote rabit . S(x,y) denote dog chases rabit . But how to execute , **please help me doing this?**

Answer (score 2):

That's not a "logic", it's a *sentence*. But yes, it's true.

To prove this, you'll mainly need the following principle of logic: $$(\exists x)\varphi \wedge (\forall x)(\varphi \rightarrow \psi) \rightarrow (\exists x) \psi$$

Since I want you to see how this kind of thing is done, I'll do this problem for you, just this once.

> **Theorem.**
>
> Assume:
>
> 1. $(\forall x)(\forall y)[(p(x) \wedge S(x,y)) \rightarrow Q(y)]$
> 2. $(\exists x)B(x)$
> 3. $(\forall x)(B(x) \rightarrow p(x))$
> 4. $(\forall x)(\exists y)S(x,y)$
>
> Then:
>
> - $(\exists x) Q(x).$

*Proof.* By 1., it suffices to show $$(\exists x) (\exists y)(p(x) \wedge S(x,y)).$$

By 3., it suffices to show $$(\exists x) (\exists y)(B(x) \wedge S(x,y)).$$

By 2., it suffices to show $$(\exists x) (\exists y)S(x,y).$$

But in the presence of 2, which guarantees the existence of an element, this follows from 4. This completes the proof.

By the way, if this is homework, you'll have to solve the problem using the specific rules / formal system given. That is, you're probably not allowed to use informal reasoning like I do here.